# i keep getting "Input string was not in a correct format" error

Tags: vb.net

I was following along in a vb.net tutorial about creating a tabular display in a listbox. Their code seems to run fine, but why is mine keep getting this error?

This is my code:

```
Public Class AdminTab

    Dim pes As String = "{0, -10}{1, -20}{2, -20}{3, - 15}"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub sadasda_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub AdminTab_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        VL.Items.Add(String.Format(pes, "Name", "Gender", "Date", "Reason"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

The only thing I tried is restart my PC and search for help online.

Comment: "why is mine keep getting this error?" - What error? You don't include any information about an error. There is nothing else about an error in your question. No error message, no error description, nothing but the sentence I quoted. What exactly is the issue you're having?

Comment: oh i put it on the title. Sorry for the confusion. The error says "Input string was not in a correct format

Answer (score 4):

```vb
Dim pes As String = "{0, -10}{1, -20}{2, -20}{3, - 15}"
```

You may be allowed the spaces before the negative signs but I'm fairly sure that you wouldn't be allowed the one between the negative sign and the number. That should almost certainly be at least this:

```vb
Dim pes As String = "{0, -10}{1, -20}{2, -20}{3, -15}"
```

but possibly even this:

```vb
Dim pes As String = "{0,-10}{1,-20}{2,-20}{3,-15}"
```

I just tested and the first option is sufficient.

Comment: oh that worked. I didnt even see that, thank you so much!

Comment: @FishyLefishe, don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem, so everyone can see that the issue is resolved without having to open the question and read the comments on the answer.